# Need Pictorial representation for the below question, (eg: histogram,swarmplot,etc)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, data-visualization

Data set given has below columns

age   sex      bmi   children   smoker    region      charges

19    female   27.9    0         no       southwest    19393.03

i need just the graph name along with the parameters to be used to achieve the below questions result.

1. i need 5 point summary of numerical attributes?
2. Distribution of bmi column
3. Measure of skewness of bmi column
4. Distribution of categorical column
5. Do charges of people who smoke differ significantly from the people who don't?
   6.Does bmi of males differ significantly from that of females?
6. Is the proportion of smokers significantly different in different genders
7. Is the distribution of bmi across women with no children, one child and two children,the same

Comment: Hi Bharathi, Have you able to solve this? Please share the details if you able to get it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/ as a good introduction to R that includes a big section on data visualisation.